# How to delete all refresh token when the user log out ? Also if they forget to logout and next time they log in and logout?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, oauth, token, refresh-token

I have this code that delete all user oauth_access_token when they logout. how do i do the same thing with the oauth_refresh_token?

Also if they forget the logout for any reason and come back, log in with new token i can still delete the access token and looking for a way to delete the oauth_refresh_token as well.

maybe a way to revoke the refresh token so on logout i can just delete all revoked token would be an option ???

```
 public function logout()
    {
      auth()->user()->tokens->each(function ($token, $key) {
         $token->delete();
      });

    return response()->json('Logged out successfully', 200);

}
```

Comment: I am using laravel passport

Answer (score 2):

Your code is just deleting the tokens from internal memory.

Access Tokens typically expire after 3600 seconds. Refresh Tokens typically never expire.

You have two options:

1. Revoke each Access Token
2. Revoke the Refresh Token that created the Access Tokens.

You do not mention which OAuth provider. For Google, to revoke either type of token call the endpoint: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}`